# I Married Farkas, and I thought he was supposed to live with me. How do I make that happen?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I married Farkas in Skyrim but everything is still the same, he talks the same and he’s not living with me. Was that supposed to change and can I make him live with me?

Comment: This sadly sounds like a bug. Do you have a save file before you married him so you can load and remarry him and see if it works properly? Have you completed all of the quests related to him? Also, are you on PC or console?

Comment: I’m on Xbox one console. Yeah. Then I tried marrying Vikas because maybe there was a problem with Farkas and the same thing happened. He talks to me the same and doesn’t live with me.

Comment: Are you sure you actually [married him](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Bonds_of_Matrimony)?

Answer (score 1):

If you talk to him and you have a house with beds for children then you can move him to that house, wherever it may be.